# Why javascript promise returns during just the initiation phase?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

I was reading into javascript promises in depth. I came across one fundamental issue with my understanding.

Here is the piece of code :

```
let p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  let a = true
  if (a) {
   resolve(console.log("a was true"));
  } else reject("a was false")
})
```

Why the above piece of code immediately logs an `a was true` even if I ***haven't*** called it as such:

```
p.then((msg) => {
  return msg
})
```

However,The following piece of code only logs the value with `.then()` calls

```
let p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  let a = true
  if (a) {
    resolve("a was true")
  } else reject("a was false")
})

p.then((msg) => {
  console.log(msg)
}).catch((msg) => {
  console.log(msg)
})
```

If someone can point out, why the very first piece of code doesnt need a `.then()` chain and does an early logs?

Please Note, I understand this is not async code, its for demo purpose only.

Comment: You're doing the equivalent of `let r = console.log("a was true"); resolve(r)`…

Answer (score 2):

The promise executor is executed immediately, even if you don't `.then` the promise.

Your first code is equivalent to

```
let p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  let a = true
  if (a) {
    let value = console.log('a was true');
    resolve(value);
  } else reject('a was false')
})
```

and as you know, `console.log()` logs the string as a side effect and returns `undefined`, so the resolved value of that promise is `undefined`.

In your second example, the resolved value of the promise is the string `"a was true"`, and nothing is logged as a side effect.